# Django: saving a User in ManyToManyField

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

What I am trying to do is to allow the authenticated users to give a like to an article.

**models.py:**

```
class NewsItem(models.Model):
  heading = models.CharField(max_length=550, blank = False)
  news_body = models.TextField(blank = True)
  ...
  likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank = True)
```

**views.py:**

```
def newsitem_slug(request, newsitem_id, slug):
  newsitem = get_object_or_404(NewsItem, pk=newsitem_id, active = 1)
  ...

  # Processing Likes:
  if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get('newsitem_like'):
    form = LikesForm(request.POST, instance=newsitem)
      if form.is_valid():
        user = User(id=request.user.id)
        if user not in newsitem.likes.all():
            newsitem.likes.add(user)
        else:
            newsitem.likes.remove(user)
  ...
```

**forms.py:**

```
class LikesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewsItem
        fields = ['likes',]
```

I get an error when adding a like:

```
Cannot add "<User: >": instance is on database "default", value is on database "None"
```

It is recommended to save both a user and an article before using the `add` method, but it does not seem to be working in my case.

What can be done about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `User` object, If you intended to do this, Save it before using it. If you intended to get a `User` object by id, Use the model manager `.get(pk=request.user.id)` to get it.